# wordpress administrator error save post with a domain idn(SEO)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a domain "idn", example: www.dómain.com, but when I save a post, wordpress removed from the url "ó" and then the page fails.
Is there any way to not remove the url the "ó" in the administrator(wp-admin)?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting your site URL/domain in wordpress’ settings in punycode notation?

Comment: Thanks CBroe,
I guess that can be fixed.
But the problem that I have is for the "SEO" in Spain, I would like that the domain do not be in "punycode notation". So my question is, if the url the wordpress could accept "ó" and do not delete it.

Comment: Browsers (and search engines) should still display the IDN version of the domain name in the address bar, even if the URLs contain the punycode version explicitly.

Comment: No swows version unicode,example ("ñ"): the second result https://www.google.es/search?q=dise%C3%B1o+web+malaga&rlz=1C1SKPL_enES428ES428&oq=dise%C3%B1o+web+malaga&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62j60.6938j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Ok perfect @CBroe, I've solved as you have told me. Only change option "siteurl" a punycode notation. How I can rate you?

Comment: Keep in mind that the home_url constant is not punycode. for this best seo. Now Perfet

Comment: @webyseo You could answer your own question describing how you managed to solve the problem (you could even accept it as an answer) to help future visitors, or simply delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!!!
I've fixed (idn) it by making the following changes:

In the config:

[siteurl] =>xn--dmain-0ta.com

[home]   => dómain.com